# Delete line N and below

Tags: notepad++

I have an xml file but I want to delete all lines below line 30 for example.

Is it possible?
Using Notepad++ or something web solution

I try using mark but all the lines are different the only thing is the same is de line number and below.

PD I have 1000 xml to edit :S

Answer (score 0):

Put cursor at start of line 32, you could use menu => **Search** => **Goto** (shortcut **Ctrl+G**) for this. Use menu => **Edit** => **Begin/End select** to start a selection. Move to end of file, use **Ctrl+End**. Use menu => **Edit** => **Begin/End select** to mark the end of the selection. Then delete the selected text. You may be able to put all of this into macro.